# ConTeXt: Use grid in margin block

Tags: context, grid-typesetting

Even though I set `grid=yes` in `\setuplayout`, margin blocks do not use the grid.

Example file:

```
\setuplayout
  [
    grid=yes,
    cutspace=6cm,
    width=fit,
    backspace=6cm,
  ]
\showgrid

\starttext
\input knuth % Properly snapped to grid

\startmarginblock
  {\tfd foobar} % Not a multiple of the line height

  \input knuth % Gets knocked off the grid
\stopmarginblock
\stoptext
```

[image: example file render]

*Note:* I do not insist on using `\startmarginblock`, but I do need a grid-aligned paragraph in the margin.

Comment: Do you really want to use different font sizes and content that's longer than the page itself in the margin?

Comment: Different font sizes – yes, I need it to include structure for contact information. But I do not need the content to be longer, that was just an example.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Friggeri CV](https://github.com/hmenke/context-examples/blob/master/cv/friggeri.tex) ([PDF](https://github.com/hmenke/context-examples/releases/download/1567391442/friggeri.pdf))?

Comment: Precisely, but I’m fond of grids. :-)

BTW, thank you very much for your guide to the documentation, it was invaluable for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why anyone would want to do this, but a line correction preceded by `\blank[overlay]` to kill the vertical space inserted by the line correction seems to work.

```
\setuplayout
  [grid=yes,
   cutspace=6cm,
   width=fit,
   backspace=6cm]
\showgrid

\starttext
\input knuth\par

\startmarginblock
  \blank[overlay]
  \startlinecorrection
    {\tfd foobar\par}
  \stoplinecorrection
  \input ward\par
  \startlinecorrection
    {\tfd barbaz\par}
  \stoplinecorrection
  \input jojomayer\par
\stopmarginblock

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Question though, how do I keep the text aligned if I wanted to use another header? Repeating the trick doesn’t seem to work…

Comment: @JurajFiala See updated answer.

Comment: Hm, I tried this approach, but it kinda falls apart once I start using different fonts. I guess it approximates the grid, but I do need the full grid functionality. :-/ Nevertheless, it does solve the original problem, so if I won’t find anything better, I’ll accept your answer. :-)